# htaccess Working fine for all but few links not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

For my work portfolio i am using htaccess for seo friendly URL and its working fine for all but for two projects its not working and going to another page (rs.php) and redirecting to home page.

Site is https://www.rsseosolution.com/seo-work-portfolio.php

At this page all projects are opening fine but Number 4 (Fair Price Movers) and number 11 (New Hampshire Lawyers) ..... these two are not opening while URL and process is same.

page name is case-studies.php

I tried by add "echo and die option" at starting of page

echo "Testing value is coming on not"; die();

But as i said that its going to another page rs.php

Using htaccess as below for our portfolio project details at case-studies.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule case-studies/(.*)-(.*)\.php$ case-studies.php?project=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule package/(.*)-(.*)\.php$ package.php?name=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule rs-(.*)\.php$ rs.php?cid=$1
```

I am not getting that why only two projects URL is going to rs.php.

What am i missing? If need any other details then please let me know.

Hope for quick response.

Comment: savi-travels-167 will $1 = savi-travels $2 = 167
fair-price-movers-164   will $1 = fair-price $2 = movers-164 
change RewriteRule case-studies/(.*)-(.*)\.php$ case-studies.php?project=$1&id=$2 
to 
RewriteRule case-studies/(.*)-([0-9]+)\.php$ case-studies.php?project=$1&id=$2

Comment: Thanks for quick response .... I changed according to your instructions but still all are working and these two project have same issue.

Comment: ok ignore my first comment :). put [L] at end of each rule so it will be 

RewriteRule case-studies/(.*)-(.*)\.php$ case-studies.php?project=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule package/(.*)-(.*)\.php$ package.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule rs-(.*)\.php$ rs.php?cid=$1 [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happen in this url `fair-price-movers-164` as it contain `rs-164` which will match the last rule.

You need to add [L] at the end of each rule to stop matching.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule case-studies/(.*)-(.*)\.php$ case-studies.php?project=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule package/(.*)-(.*)\.php$ package.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule rs-(.*)\.php$ rs.php?cid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks ...... Now all issue fix. Thanks lots for your quick and valuable suggestion.  And i learn one new point that [L] is stop rule matching. Thanks